# How many solutions does $\cos(2x) = -\frac{1}{3}$ have in the interval $]-7\pi,10\pi]$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> How many solutions does $\cos(2x) = -\frac{1}{3}$ have in the interval
>   $]-7\pi,10\pi]$?
>
> A. 9 $$\\$$
>
> B. 17 $$\\$$
>
> C. 18
>
> $$\\$$
>
> D. 34

I can solve this using the calculator but the problem is that this has a ridiculous amount of solutions. Since this can't be solved analytically (I think) does my book expect me to count through every one of them?

Is there a property of some more straightforward way of solving this? Maybe something to do with the period of the function?

Also, can this be solved analytically?

Comment: HINT:  $\cos(2x)$ is $\pi$-periodic.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yep, I got it. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The period of $\cos(2x)$ is $\pi$ and $|10\pi|+|-7\pi| = 17\pi$. The function repeats itself 17 times and for each time $-\frac{1}{3}$ happens twices, thus $17\cdot 2 = 34$.

The right answer is D.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $f : x \mapsto \cos 2 x$ is a $\pi$-periodic and continous function, so it traverses all values of the interval $[-1 , 1]$ two times exactly in all the interval $[a , b]$ such that $b - a = \pi$, by the intermediate values theorem. In this case, you can use a similar argument to prove that $2 \cdot 17 = 34$ is the correct answer because there is a family of intervals ${\{J_k\}}_{k = 1}^{17}$, with $J_i \cap J_j = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$ ($i , j \in \{1 , \ldots , 17\}$) and the length of $J_k$ is $\pi$ for all $k = 1 , \ldots , 17$, such that
$$
(- 7 \pi , 10 \pi] = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{17} J_k\mbox{,}
$$
being
$J_k = ((k - 8) \pi , (k - 7) \pi]$ for all $k = 1 , \ldots , 17$.